# javascript I can not catch the syntax error

Tags: javascript, try-catch, syntax-error

I'm working on a project which needs to use youtube api. The html and javascript works fine in different browsers. Yet When I just WPF's webbrowser to run it, I get the following error:

```
Script Error
line:1
char:1
Error: Syntax Error
Code:0
URL about://:/

Do you want to continue running scripts on this page?
yes no
```

When I click yes, the message box went away and the program just works fine. I comment out most of the content on the html file and found that the following sentence caused this problem:

```
google.load("swfobject", "2.1");
```

So now, I just want to catch this error, just don't want the messagebox to popup. I tried

```
try{
      google.load("swfobject", "2.1");
}catch(err)
 {alert("caught");}
```

Yet, I still get the initial error box. Is there anyway to remove the error box? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't actually use `try/catch` blocks to catch syntax errors.  A syntax error means that the parser can't correctly parse the JavaScript.  Syntax errors happen *before* the code is ran.